# Ajax not sending data to Spring Controller

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

I am new to Ajax, so please bear with me. I have a jsp page that supposed to send selected dates in an array form along with int id and string type to the controller. I am using Keith Wood Datepicker. But whenever I am trying to send the data it is giving me error. The console log error is:

```
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolverlogException
          WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Required int parameter 'id' is not present
```

Below is my jsp code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#first').datepick({multiSelect: 99, showTrigger: '#calImg'});
           $("#getDates").click(function () {

             var dates = $('#first').datepick('getDate');

            //Create a HTML Table element.
             var table = $("<table />");

            //Add the data rows.
            for (var i = 0; i < dates.length; i++) {
                row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                    var cell = $("<td />");
                    cell.html($.datepick.formatDate('DD, MM d,  yyyy',dates[i]));
                    row.append(cell);

            }

            var dvTable = $("#getSelect");
            dvTable.html("");
            dvTable.append(table);
        });
     $('#clearDates').click(function(){    

          $('#first').datepick('clear');
          $('#getSelect').empty();

          });


        $('#second').datepick({ 
            rangeSelect: true, monthsToShow: [1, 2]}); 
        var dateRange = [];
        $("#getRange").click(function () {

             var dates = $('#second').datepick('getDate');
            for(var i=0; i<dates.length; i++){
                dateRange.push(dates[i]);
            }
            //Create a HTML Table element.
            var table = $("<table />");

            //Add the data rows.
            for (var i = 0; i < dateRange.length-1; i++) {
                row = $(table[0].insertRow(-1));
                    var cell = $("<td />");
                    cell.html($.datepick.formatDate('DD, MM d,     yyyy',dateRange[i])+" <b> To </b>" + $.datepick.formatDate('DD, MM d,     yyyy',dateRange[i+1]) + "<br />");
                    i++;
                row.append(cell);

            }

            var dvTable = $("#getSelectRange");
            dvTable.html("");
            dvTable.append(table);
        });
     $('#clearRangeDates').click(function(){    

          $('#second').datepick('clear');
          $('#getSelectRange').empty();
          dateRange = [];
          });
     $('#start').datepick({showTrigger: '#calImg'});
     $('#end').datepick({showTrigger: '#calImg'});
     $('#submitDates').click(function(){
         var dateRandom = $('#first').datepick('getDate');
         var id = 1;
         var type = "random";
         $.ajax({
               url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendarData",
                dataType: "json",
                traditional: true,
                data: $.param({ "id": id, "dates": dateRandom, "type":     type}, true),
                type: "POST",
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(data)     {$('#first').datepick({multiSelect: 99, showTrigger: '#calImg'});},
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + e);
                 }
            });
     });

});


</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="page-header">
  <h2>Choose your dates:</h2>
 </div>     
  <div class="row">
   <h4>Choose By Day:</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="first" style="background-color:lavender;">

      <img id="calImg" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources    /script/calendar-    blue.gif" alt="Popup" class="trigger"> </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="isoDate" style="background-    color:lavenderblush;">
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table">
      <tr><td colspan="2" class="c_button"><input type="button"     value="Get Date" id="getDates" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="getSelect"></div></td></tr>
       <tr><td class="c_button"><input type="button" value="Clear Date"     id="clearDates" /></td>
          <td class="c_button"><input type="button" value="Submit Date"     id="submitDates" /></td></tr>
      </table> 
      </div>
     </div>
  </div>

  <br /><br />
  <div class="row">
    <h4>Choose By Range:</h4>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="second" style="background-color:lavender;">

    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6" id="second_iso" style="background-    color:lavenderblush;">
    <div class="table-responsive">
     <table class="table">
      <tr><td colspan="2" class="c_button"><input type="button"     value="Get Date Range" id="getRange" /></td></tr>
      <tr><td colspan="2"><div id="getSelectRange"></div></td></tr>
      <tr><td class="c_button"><input type="button" value="Clear Date"     id="clearRangeDates" /></td>
          <td class="c_button"><input type="button" value="Submit Date     Range" id="submitRangeDates" /></td></tr>
      </table> 
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br /><br />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12" id="third_iso" style="background-    color:lavender;">
      <h4>Recurring Event:</h4>
      <form action="" method="post">
      <div class="table-responsive">
      <table id="recur" class="table">
        <tr>
          <td><b>Start Date: </b><input id="start" type="text"     name="start" class="form-control" /><span class="pop"><img id="calImg"     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/calendar-blue.gif"     alt="Popup" class="trigger" /></span></td>
          <td><b>End Date: </b><input id="end" type="text" name="end"     class="form-control" /><span class="pop"><img id="calImg"     src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/calendar-blue.gif"     alt="Popup" class="trigger" /></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
           <b>Repeat Event: </b>
           <select name="repeat" class="form-control">
             <option value="Daily">Daily</option>
             <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
             <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
           </select>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn     btn-primary btn-md"/></td></tr>
      </table>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!--  <div class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:lavenderblush;">
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem     accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque     ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae     vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
    </div>-->
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

My controller class is:

```
@Controller
public class ScheduleController {

    private DatesService datesService;

    public void setDatesService(DatesService datesService){
         this.datesService = datesService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String showHome(){
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/calendar")
    public String showCalendar(){
        return "calendar";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/calendarData", method = RequestMethod.POST,
            produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes =     MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)
    @ResponseBody
    public String showCalendarData(@RequestParam("id") int id,         @RequestParam("dates[]") LocalDate[] dates, 
    @RequestParam("type") String type){

        for(int i=0; i < dates.length; i++){
            datesService.create_random(dates[i], type, id);
        }
        return "calendar";
    }

}
```

Here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.neiu.scheduler</groupId>
  <artifactId>scheduler</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.38</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: @turboemu It did not work

Comment: @turboemu Getting error WARNING: Handler execution resulted in exception: Content type 'application/json;charset=utf-8' not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my ajax code as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submitDates').click(function(){
         var dateRandom = $('#first').datepick('getDate');
         var dates = JSON.stringify(dateRandom);
         // var id = 1;
        //var type = "random";
         alert("hi");
         $.ajax({
               url: "${pageContext.request.contextPath}/calendarData?id=1&type='random'",
               dataType: "json",                
                data : dates,
                type: "POST",
                contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                success: function(response) {
                    alert("Success: " + response);
                    //$('#first').datepick({multiSelect: 99, showTrigger: '#calImg'});

                    },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error: ' + 'Not working');
                 }
            });
         event.preventDefault();
     });
```

My controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/calendarData", method = RequestMethod.POST)

    @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.OK)

    public @ResponseBody String showCalendarData(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id,
                                     @RequestBody(required = false) String[] dates, 
                                     @RequestParam(value = "type") String type){
......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `id` parameter in your ajax call is being passed in the body of an HTTP POST. But your controller is expecting an `id` parameter to be present as a request parameter in the URL e.g. `http://localhost:8080/myApp?id=123`.

So the error message is accurate, there is no request parameter called `id`. Instead you have are passing `id` in the request body.

You could either pass your values as part of the URL with a GET request (update your AJAX call). Or use `@RequestBody` to get the request body and  validate its contents another way (update the Java).

**Edit:**
@user5715620, do you have Jackson on your classpath? If using Maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

Spring should pick it up if it's included on the class path and use it to serialize/deserialize the request/response.

**Edit 2:** @user5715620, have you tidied up your controller method? In the OP you have the `@ResponseBody` annotation, which means that the the return value for that method will be sent as the response body, you also have the method setup to produce JSON. However you are returning the name of a JSP, namely 'calendar'. The string 'calendar' is not valid JSON.

What have you updated the arguments to the `showCalendarData` to be? Perhaps update the OP to reflect your current state. I'd expect it to be something like `showCalendarData(@ResponseBody String jsonString)`. First just log that string. Once you know you are receiving the data you could use Jackson to parse the jsonString and extract the values you need. (You can have the type of `jsonString` be a custom type and have Jackson serialize it but in your case I'd add that improvement later).

How are you deploying your application? Ensure all your dependencies are being deployed to the container. If using Eclipse you can check the deployment assembly in the project properties.

Try to understand what your are expecting to happen and do some investigation yourself. Don't blindly apply my suggestions and come back with the next issue.

Comment: @matsev I included my pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally figured it out.